# Recreate folder structure using md5 hashes

Tags: files, scripting, backup, data-recovery, hashsum

Given a long list of md5 checksums and copies of these files, renamed and in different folder structures: How can I recreate or recover the original filesystem structure? Assuming no hash collisions.

````
be70e389a9e000a85826a1a80488e1e1  path/A/2/2.bin
96a48d4706ec8eafff7e56f6784bb6b4  path/B/b1.bin
ffd2e58da118ba6c85de29c4c5b4c1f8  path/C/c1.bin
dbde0b664f88d8027e5cb7efb2cd1060  path/C/2/c2.bin
...```
````

Comment: Just in case this was what you were thinking, I feel obligated to point you in [this direction](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60854/is-it-possible-to-create-a-file-given-an-md5-hash).

Comment: @KGIII haha, no ;)

Answer (score 1):

With `bash` I would:

1. Iterate over the file with `read` and store each hash into an [associative array](https://linuxhint.com/associative_array_bash/)
2. Store off all local file names into a temporary file (using `find` should be fine).
3. Iterate over the list of local files running `md5sum` on each, checking if the hash is in the array as a key, and if so renaming it to the target name.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `join` for a quick and dirty solution, assuming that the filenames used for restoring the folders have no blank characters:

```
md5sum * | sort -u -k 1,1 | join - ../restore.s | \
  while read h r t; do \
    mkdir -p $(dirname "tmp/$t"); cp "$r" "tmp/$t"; \
  done
```

The inputs for join needed sorting and I removed identical files. The output of the join is then lines of `hash source target` used to restore the files.